# fgets() feeds \n to the subsequent string, not taking input

Tags: c, structure

I'm trying to input names for an array of structures. Though this is working fine for the 1st iteration, in the 2nd iteration, the **name** string of the structure  object receives **\n** and I don't know why that is.

I've tried the fflush(stdin) as well but it doesn't seem to work out :/

```
struct employee
{
    char ac_no[20], name[30];
    float balance;
};

void getdata (struct employee *);
void getdata(struct employee *ptr)
{
    printf("Enter Name: ");
    fgets(ptr->name, 29, stdin);
    ptr->name[strcspn((ptr->name), "\r\n")] = 0;
    printf("Enter Account Number: ");
    fgets(ptr->ac_no, 19, stdin);
    printf("Enter Balance: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &(ptr->balance));
    fflush(stdin);
}

//In Main()
struct employee emp[5];
register int i;
for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
{
    printf("\nEmployee %d: \n", (i+1));
        getdata(&emp[i]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with gets() too, the subsequent structure entities are getting **\n** as the **name** string.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is UB, and you don't need to pass `sizeof(x) - 1` in `fgets`, just pass `fgets(arr, sizeof arr, ...);`: `fgets` reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str __until (num-1)__ characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

Comment: Don't use fflush(stdin). This won't work for the intended purpose.

Comment: @AlterMann yeah okay, I'll do that. But that doesn't solve the problem of "\n" being fed into the name of the structure objects that follow.

Comment: @GineetMehta, as I said `fflush(stdin);` is UB, try to consume/flush the trailing new line using `int c; while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't consume `\n`, so `\n` is still in `stdin` and read by `fgets` in next iteration. `fflush(stdin)` is not in standard C, so the behavior is undefined.

You can consume the newline after `scanf_s` using `getc`:

```
...
fgets(ptr->ac_no, 19, stdin);
printf("Enter Balance: ");
scanf_s("%f", &(ptr->balance));
getc(stdin);
```